# http.request listener

Tags: java, playframework

I need my Play! application to accept http POST from other server.
Is there some simple way how to manage external http post, get data and sent response?
Some easy http request listener?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say nearly ALL http requests come from a remote source, so this is how Play and all HTTP based containers works by default!

However, to offer some advice, as you are sharing data between servers, and not a client-browser, I would check out `renderXml` and `renderJSON` in your controllers to return data in a way that your server will expect (as it is unlikely to be expecting HTML content??).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Codemwnci - besides those tips you can take a look in the 'routes' file and mark your method to accept only POST:

```
POST    /edit    controllerName.methodName
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Answers, once I have the routes, it is really easy to write controller:

```
public static void accept(){
    InputStream inputStream = request.body;
    ...
    String response = "cmd=asynch-no-trace";
    renderText(response);
}
```